# How to configure confluence clustering?

Tags: confluence

```
     I found this link where I can setup confluence clustering.But I am not
```

able to understand how to set it up.

https://developer.atlassian.com/confdev/development-resources/confluence-developer-faq/how-do-i-ensure-my-add-on-works-properly-in-a-cluster/starting-a-confluence-cluster-on-a-single-machine

Step1:Copy 'confluence-1' and 'home-1', and name them 'confluence-2' and 'home-2'.

I have setup two instances of confluence lets call it Centos 1 and Centos 2,Which folders should be copied to which server?

Step 2:Set the home directory for the second node to 'home-2':

I do not understand this as I do not know which place I need to configure this.

Step 3: Alter the Tomcat server for 'confluence-2' to use different ports from 'confluence-1':

Is this port configuration required if two instances have different IP addresses.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

All folders should be copied along with their "home" directory. The "home" folder may not be named home and may reside somewhere else (not under Centos folder). Centos 2 is an exact copy of Centos 1. 
You configure Centos 2's "home" directory to point to the copied home directory. You configure it here `Centos 2 folder/confluence/WEB-INF/classes/confluence-init.properties`. This way each Confluence server points to its own home directory. The properties file looks something like this:

```
# This file allows you to set the directory for Confluence to store its configuration files.
#
###########################
# Note for Windows Users  #
###########################
#
# Each backslash in your path must be written as a forward slash.
# - For example:
# c:\confluence\data
#
# should be written as:
#
# c:/confluence/data

###########################
# Configuration Directory #
###########################

# specify your directory below (don't forget to remove the '#' in front)

confluence.home=c:/confluence/data-2
```

This is done on a single machine so you need to configure Confluence to run on different ports otherwise they will clash.

If you are doing this on separate machines (i.e., one machine per Confluence server) then you don't need to do any copying of the "home" and Centos directories. You also don't need to change the port configuration. Just install Confluence on machine one then install Confluence on machine two. Then start the first server and once it's ready to server (`init Confluence is ready to serve`), start the second server. After that go to **General Configuration -> Clustering**, you should be able to see the nodes running.